# Unable to Find vcvarsall.bat Windows 10 Python 3.5.1

Tags: python, windows, numpy

I'm having an issue installing numpy on Windows 10 x64 with python 3.5.1. When I type pip install numpy, I get the error: unable to find vcvarsall.bat. I've also gotten this error from attempting to install other libraries.

From doing my research on the problem, I know it's related to the Visual C++ compiler for Python, or Visual Studio, as suggested in this answer and others: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10558328/1745715 I've installed both of these (Visual studio 2015, as it is my understanding that 2015 is what I want for python 3.5.1), and can verify that they have added values to my PATH. I've also rebooted the system since. No matter what I try, I still get the error when attempting to install numpy (and other packages) from pip. Could it be that I need a different version of Visual Studio for this version of Python?

I know there are many questions on SO involving similar situations, so before someone marks this a duplicate: I have read them all, and have not found any answer to work for me. Moreover, most of them do not relate to this environment (windows 10 x64, python 3.5.1). The nearest answer was one regarding Python 3.5 on Windows 10 x64 while installing numpy using pip, but the suggestion (to used a precompiled version of numpy and avoid the pip install) was unsatisfactory, as I have other libraries I have to install via pip that are also experiencing the same issues, so I need the compiler to work correctly.

Comment: For my computer (same windows/python) I'm using VC14 together with Anaconda distribution. But I'm no expert, there might be ways to make it work with VC15. You might get away with just linking your VC15 as ``VS140COMNTOOLS``.

Comment: Actually, it looks as though I already had VS14 installed, and the VS140COMNTOOLS linking. In fact, VS15 only added two values to the path var, but not any new system vars like the VS140COMNTOOLS from VS14.